# Azure Devops - create a map variable for each deployment environment

Tags: azure-devops, yaml

I have a need to download a certificate file from Azure Secure filestorage when deploying a microservice.  I have about a dozen microservices with about 6 lifecycles/environments each.  The certificates names do not follow a strict naming convention.
I would like to create a variable hashmap/map/associative array.

I tried inputting these as a parameter in azure-pipeline.yaml

```yaml
- name: sslCerts
  type: object 
  default:
  - environmentName: Development
    sslCertificate: service1-dev.p12
    sslCertificateKey: service1-dev
  - environmentName: Sandbox
    sslCertificate: service1-sbxdev.p12
    sslCertificateKey: service-sbxdev-key
```

But I could not figure out how to dereference them:

```yaml
jobs: 
  # ######################## Stage: Terraform Plan and Apply in Dev ########################
  - template: ../azure-pipelines-template/apply-stages.yml
    parameters:
      sslCertificate: ${{ parameters.sslCerts[${{ parameters.envName }} ].sslCertificate)
```

I then tried plan 'B' to write a powershell script to output simple variables.  It failed as the DownLoadSecureFile task errors before the job starts running (Secure file not found).  So the below code never gets a chance to run.

```
$DeploymentPath = $args[0]

$certs = @{
    Sandbox = {
        certName = "sbx-cert"
        certKey  = "sbx-cert-key"
    }
    Development = {
        certName = "dev-cert"
        certKey  = "dev-cert-key"
    }

}

$cert = $certs[$DeploymentPath]

# These Magic Codes create variable in Azure Devops 
write-output "##vso[task.setvariable variable=sslCertificate]$cert.certName"
write-output "##vso[task.setvariable variable=sslCertificateKeyFile]$cert.certKey"
```

I don't really want to create 70+ variable files (each combination of microservice and environment).  Is there some interpolation of object parameters that I'm missing.
Can I duplicate the DownloadSecureFile task in a script or terraform and take it out of AzureDevops yaml?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're very close, two things need changing:

1. Declare your parameter as map (not as array):

   ```yaml
   parameter:
   - name: sslCerts
     type: object 
     default:
       Development:
         sslCertificate: service1-dev.p12
         sslCertificateKey: service1-dev
       Sandbox:
         sslCertificate: service1-sbxdev.p12
         sslCertificateKey: service-sbxdev-key
   ```

   This way the environment name becomes key, which you can use when referencing.
2. Once you're inside `${{ }}`, there's no need to nest it:

   ```yaml
   jobs: 
   # ######################## Stage: Terraform Plan and Apply in Dev ########################
   - template: ../azure-pipelines-template/apply-stages.yml
     parameters:
       sslCertificate: ${{ parameters.sslCerts[parameters.envName].sslCertificate $}}
   ```

Comment: Thanks, those changes are working for me!